# uniquely identify an outlook installation in an addon

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

Is there a way to get some sort of unique identifier for an outlook installation?

I’ll explain more.

I’m looking at developing a outlook ribbon add-on (and owa addon with the VSTO) where you can run actions based on specific types of messages coming in.  The actions would be API calls to a backend service.

I need a way to uniquely identify an outlook installation.  Not just the userid or mailboxid because users can roam around.  Likewise IP address is DHCP so that’s no good either.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you need to have unique identification of particular installation, you probably need to do this during installation. At install time set some unique registry key. Your VSTO add-in would read this key and pass it to your API calls.

Answer (score 0):

During installation, like Slava suggested, or at very first Outlook run with your add-in installed you may generate the required ID, for example, using the following code:

```
Guid.NewGuid()
```

See the [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx) structure for more information. A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required. Such an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.